# How to use sockets and timers without blocking each other?

Tags: c++, sockets, timer

My project is a job server that stores commands received by UDP in a queue. Every command has an interval value to be executed and an timeout value to be removed. These actions are controlled by a timer that must run independent of the server code, like 2 processes.

What's the best way to make a server and a timer running without blocking each other? I am thinking about threads or asynchronous calls but I'm new to C++ and I don't know how to apply these ideas in my code.

I'm using Visual C++ 2010 and ASIO from Boost 1.48.

Thanks!

Comment: Threading is one solution, but if you can guarantee that processing your timed events doesn't take too long, you could do everything in one thread with a single main loop and signal handlers. Single-threaded programming is a lot easier, so it's worth considering your options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule an asynchronous (non-blocking) `deadline_timer` with Boost ASIO, as introduced here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html

I assume you are using ASIO for your UDP communication already (since you mentioned both)--now it's just a matter of scheduling the timers you need in your event loop, and everything should just work.

Comment: The first time I read the answer I didn't get what "scheduling the timers you need in your event loop" means, but comparing the code in the link you posted with my code, I understood that is not the responsability of my code to do the scheduling. If I'm not wrong, the trick was to hook the timer to the same io_service my server is hooking and let the io_service do the job. A simple solution that could be reached even without a question here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this in one thread by using "non-blocking socket" and manually calculated timer (for example using ticks from start of application, usable in SDL), but this would cause high CPU usage.

Multiple threads sounds much better, but there's multiple variants how to do this.
For example: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815805 or pthreads under the linux.

Google for "multithread visual C++ 2010" should tell you much more.